# Where can I see the shortcuts for adding different meshes?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

Where can I see the shortcuts AFTER the shift+A to add menu? e.g. shift+A, M, C gives me a cube. I'd like to learn the other ones too, but I don't even know where to find the right keys.

Comment: See what letter of the primitive is underlined, for example the P of Plane is underlined, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, I can't believe I never saw those underlines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what letter of the primitive is underlined, for example the P of Plane is underlined.